# Can Root CA Certificate located in the middle of certificate path?

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509, ca

I made a program that connects to website(tls) and save certificate chain to files.

Sometimes certificate chain from a website is looking different from what I expected.

One of this certificate chain is issued from Sectigo(ex Comodo) CA.

I think "AddTrust External CA Root" should located in the last certificate of chain but is located in second certificate in its chain.(please look at below Certificate chain part )

```
$ openssl  s_client -showcerts -connect adblockplus.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 serialNumber = HRB 73508, jurisdictionC = DE, businessCategory = Private Organization, C = DE, postalCode = 50825, ST = Nordrhein-Westfalen, L = K\C3\B6ln, street = Lichtstra\C3\9Fe 25, O = Eyeo GmbH, OU = COMODO EV SSL, CN = www.adblockplus.org
verify return:1

---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/serialNumber=HRB 73508/jurisdictionC=DE/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=DE/postalCode=50825/ST=Nordrhein-Westfalen/L=K\xC3\xB6ln/street=Lichtstra\xC3\x9Fe 25/O=Eyeo GmbH/OU=COMODO EV SSL/CN=www.adblockplus.org
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 3 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/serialNumber=HRB 73508/jurisdictionC=DE/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=DE/postalCode=50825/ST=Nordrhein-Westfalen/L=K\xC3\xB6ln/street=Lichtstra\xC3\x9Fe 25/O=Eyeo GmbH/OU=COMODO EV SSL/CN=www.adblockplus.org
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
```

my question is:

1. Is this case is normal?
2. Is the web server(adblockplus this time) making Certificate path ?
3. How to determine valid certificate path?

Any comments are welcome. thanks

Comment: There are two chains due to the cross signing. There is more than on valid path.https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=adblockplus.org&latest

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon: there _are_ alternate paths but this server isn't _sending_ them; SSLLabs knows how to explore commonly used paths on its own bat, as do some clients (especially browsers) _not_ including OpenSSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TLS-was-SSL server is *supposed to* send the certificate chain in the correct order in the handshake, but some don't, and most clients including OpenSSL will still handle it correctly, by matching up issuer=subject names, as long as the leaf (end-entity) cert is *first*. Note the trace of the validation process:

```
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = New Jersey, L = Jersey City, O = The USERTRUST Network, CN = USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = Sectigo Limited, CN = Sectigo RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 serialNumber = HRB 73508, jurisdictionC = DE, businessCategory = Private Organization, C = DE, postalCode = 50825, ST = Nordrhein-Westfalen, L = K\C3\B6ln, street = Lichtstra\C3\9Fe 25, O = Eyeo GmbH, OU = COMODO EV SSL, CN = www.adblockplus.org
verify return:1
```

You can see that the certificates were *used* in the correct top-to-bottom order even though they weren't *received* in the correct bottom-to-top order.

This misbehavior is common enough TLS 1.3 was changed to officially permit it. Compare TLS 1.2 in [RFC 5246 7.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2):

> certificate_list ... The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

to TLS 1.3 in [RFC 8446 4.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2), emphasis added:

> ... The sender's certificate MUST come in the first
> CertificateEntry in the list.  Each following certificate **SHOULD**
> directly certify the one immediately preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed
> independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
> omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
> possess any omitted certificates.

> Note: Prior to TLS 1.3, "certificate_list" ordering required each
> certificate to certify the one immediately preceding it; however,
> some implementations allowed some flexibility.  Servers sometimes
> send both a current and deprecated intermediate for transitional
> purposes, and others are simply configured incorrectly, but these
> cases can nonetheless be validated properly.  For maximum
> compatibility, all implementations SHOULD be prepared to handle
> potentially extraneous certificates and arbitrary orderings from any
> TLS version, with the exception of the end-entity certificate which
> MUST be first.

(And the same is true in the other direction for client certificates, but they are used only very rarely, while server certificates almost always are.)